# Does this tire need to be replaced

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

[image]

Caught the curb a bit and can’t decide it I need to replace the tire or if it’s repairable. I don’t see any side wall or change in color on the tire.  Any opinions would be appreciated

Comment: No, it just peeled the rim guard part of the tire a small amount, it safe.

Comment: Answer the question, @Moab :o) ... Nobody is going to refute what you're saying. It's a scrub and not much more.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! (This one is to the OP!)

Comment: It may have unbalanced the wheel for highway resonances which may propagate the tear.